# Spring-boot:run works but java-jar doesn't

Tags: java, spring, web-services

The application is an integration WS (exposes an endpoint whose operations call a third-party WS). The application worked correctly with http, but when the third party added its own certificate and forced the use of https, it stopped working.

I have created the jks, and I have managed to generate the third-party wsdl classes. The application compiles and executes `mvn spring-boot: run -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore = MiJks.jks` works correctly. On the other hand, if I use `java -jar Miapp.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore = MiJks.jks`, it is not able to create the beans of the 3rd services.

To generate the wsdl code of the 3rd, I use jaxws-maven-plugin from codehaus.

This is the definition of the bean within the application-context:

```
<bean id="teleoptiInternalService"
        class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="serviceInterface"
            value="com.teleopti.ccc.schemas.sdk._2010._04.TeleoptiCccSdkInternal" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl"
             value="https://WTWFMWEB01.comunicaciones.tel/TeleoptiWFM/SDK/TeleoptiCccSdkService.svc?wsdl" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="TeleoptiCccSdkService" />
        <property name="portName" value="TeleoptiOrganizationService1" />
        <!-- TODO Endpoint URL should be in a properties file -->
        <property name="endpointAddress"
            value="https://WTWFMWEB01.comunicaciones.tel/TeleoptiWFM/SDK/TeleoptiCccSdkService.svc" />
        <property name="handlerResolver" ref="wsHandlerResolver" />
        <property name="portFeatures">
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This is the error showed :

```
2018-05-28 10:32:55.623  WARN 2172 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Bean creation exception on non-lazy FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teleoptiInternalService' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-teleopti-integration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
```

What's wrong? What's the difference between running java through maven and running the java directly?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you put the `-D` before the `-jar`?

Comment: Thank you chrylis, that was the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Put -D before -jar while executing java command